# Removing a node in d3 grapth on node.js

Tags: node.js, d3.js

My problem is same this, please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYStf/4/).

I remove a node, and add a new node in d3 graph, but I still can see the removed node in graph.

The "ios" is added but dont see in the "svg". What's wrong?

```
function dynamicAddNodes() {        
    var updatedata = {
        "name":"ios",
        "NumOccurrences":"500",
        "color":"green",
        "x":0,
        "y":1
    }

    data.nodes.pop();                    
    data.nodes.push(updatedata);
    restart();
}
```

Comment: You're only removing the node from the data structure that the force layout uses internally. You also need to remove the actual SVG element.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff pleas see  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYStf/4/)

Comment: I've had a look at your fiddle -- I'm telling you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes! I resolve it:

```
circles = circles.data(data.nodes,function (d) {
     return d.id; 
  });
```

see [jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/5r62N/](http://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/5r62N/)